# Where can I find information on Kent 700c Eagle Ridge axle nuts, I want to buy Hexlox

Tags: wheels, compatibility, replacement, axle, security

Where can I find information on Kent 700c Eagle Ridge front and rear outer axle nuts, so they can be replaced with Hexlox?

Comment: What are the thread dimensions?

Comment: I can't find out much info your bike, other than the fact it's an entry level BSO sold by the likes of Amazon and eBay. The Hexlox is going to be as dear as buying another bike of the same quality. In this instance ask yourself the question why you need the Hexlox? Is it for security? If so you may be better with a decent D Lock around half the price of the Hexlox

Comment: @DanielRHicks Isn't that basically the question?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - So the answer is:  Haul the front wheel to a bike shop or hardware store and get the axle measured.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest and most reliable way to find out for the bike would be by measuring directly. The Hexnuts come in M9, M10, or 3/8 sizes and then all are said to take a 6mm Hexlox. From reading here: https://hexlox.com/collections/hexlox-compatible-extras/products/hexnut-wheel-nut-lock

Extract from same page:

> FRONT WHEEL: 
>   most Front Wheels use M9
>   If your Front Wheel Nut fits your rear wheel or its for VanMoof, Miche and DuraAce, use M10 For vintage bikes please double check. 
>   3/8 is rarely used. Best to check your axle diameter.
>
> FOR REAR WHEEL:
>   most Rear Wheels use M10x1mm
>   Fits all Single Speed and Fixed rear wheels.
>   Also suitable for Rohloff, Bion-X, NuVinci, VanMoof Front and Rear, Miche Front and Rear, DuraAce Front and Rear.
>
> FOR SHIMANO ALFINE/NEXUS. 
>   Select: Rear 3/8 - Alfine/Nexus 
>   (3/8' x 26tpi)